# Laravel - Check & Make eager load of relational model.

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'am trying to check if the record has relation and at the same time I want to make an eager load so:

```
User::has('item')->with('item')->get();
```

I've noticed that `with` method do not check if the record has a relation, is this the right sequence or there are a shorter way to code this?

Comment: I tried with a non-existent relation,  and it's throw an exception `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::foo()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
// Pull all blog users that have
// at least one related model/item
$users = User::has('item')->get();
```

Instead of this:

```
User::has('item')->with('item')->get();
```

Reference on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations).